# como recorrer un subarray con php

Tags: php, json, api

Esta es una parte del **JSON** que me traigo del API https://restcountries.com/ aca les dejo en link en el cual uso esta API para traer la información que necesito. Actualmente esta informacion me trae cuando busco el continente **America** y este...

```
[
    {
        "name": {
        "common": "Bolivia",
        "official": "Plurinational State of Bolivia",
        "nativeName": {
            "aym": {
                "official": "Wuliwya Suyu",
                "common": "Wuliwya"
            },
            "grn": {
                "official": "Tetã Volívia",
                "common": "Volívia"
            },
            "que": {
                "official": "Buliwya Mamallaqta",
                "common": "Buliwya"
            },
            "spa": {
                "official": "Estado Plurinacional de Bolivia",
                "common": "Bolivia"
            }
        }
    },
    "tld": [
        ".bo"
    ],
    "cca2": "BO",
    "ccn3": "068",
    "cca3": "BOL",
    "cioc": "BOL",
    "independent": true,
    "status": "officially-assigned",
    "unMember": true,
    "currencies": {
        "BOB": {
            "name": "Bolivian boliviano",
            "symbol": "Bs."
        }
    },
    "idd": {
        "root": "+5",
        "suffixes": [
            "91"
        ]
    },
    "capital": [
        "Sucre"
    ],
    "altSpellings": [
        "BO",
        "Buliwya",
        "Wuliwya",
        "Bolivia, Plurinational State of",
        "Plurinational State of Bolivia",
        "Estado Plurinacional de Bolivia",
        "Buliwya Mamallaqta",
        "Wuliwya Suyu",
        "Tetã Volívia"
    ],
    "region": "Americas",
    "subregion": "South America",
    "languages": {
        "aym": "Aymara",
        "grn": "Guaraní",
        "que": "Quechua",
        "spa": "Spanish"
    },
    "translations": {
        "ara": {
            "official": "دولة بوليفيا المتعددة القوميات",
            "common": "بوليفيا"
        },
        "ces": {
            "official": "Mnohonárodnostní stát Bolívie",
            "common": "Bolívie"
        },
        "cym": {
            "official": "Gweriniaeth Bolifia",
            "common": "Bolifia"
        },
        "deu": {
            "official": "Plurinationaler Staat Bolivien",
            "common": "Bolivien"
        },
        "est": {
            "official": "Boliivia Paljurahvuseline Riik",
            "common": "Boliivia"
        },
        "fin": {
            "official": "Bolivian monikansainen valtio",
            "common": "Bolivia"
        },
        "fra": {
            "official": "État plurinational de Bolivie",
            "common": "Bolivie"
        },
        "hrv": {
            "official": "Plurinational State of Bolivia",
            "common": "Bolivija"
        },
        "hun": {
            "official": "Bolíviai Többnemzetiségű Állam",
            "common": "Bolívia"
        },
        "ita": {
            "official": "Stato Plurinazionale della Bolivia",
            "common": "Bolivia"
        },
        "jpn": {
            "official": "ボリビアの多民族国",
            "common": "ボリビア多民族国"
        },
        "kor": {
            "official": "볼리비아 다민족국",
            "common": "볼리비아"
        },
        "nld": {
            "official": "Plurinationale Staat van Bolivia",
            "common": "Bolivia"
        },
        "per": {
            "official": "جمهوری بولیوی",
            "common": "بولیوی"
        },
        "pol": {
            "official": "Wielonarodowe Państwo Boliwia",
            "common": "Boliwia"
        },
        "por": {
            "official": "Estado Plurinacional da Bolívia",
            "common": "Bolívia"
        },
        "rus": {
            "official": "Многонациональное Государство Боливия",
            "common": "Боливия"
        },
        "slk": {
            "official": "Bolívijská republika",
            "common": "Bolívia"
        },
        "spa": {
            "official": "Estado Plurinacional de Bolivia",
            "common": "Bolivia"
        },
        "swe": {
            "official": "Mångnationella staten Bolivia",
            "common": "Bolivia"
        },
        "urd": {
            "official": "جمہوریہ بولیویا",
            "common": "بولیویا"
        },
        "zho": {
            "official": "多民族玻利维亚国",
            "common": "玻利维亚"
        }
    },
    "latlng": [
        -17.0,
        -65.0
    ],
    "landlocked": true,
    "borders": [
        "ARG",
        "BRA",
        "CHL",
        "PRY",
        "PER"
    ],
    "area": 1098581.0,
    "demonyms": {
        "eng": {
            "f": "Bolivian",
            "m": "Bolivian"
        },
        "fra": {
            "f": "Bolivienne",
            "m": "Bolivien"
        }
    },
    "flag": "",
    "maps": {
        "googleMaps": "https://goo.gl/maps/9DfnyfbxNM2g5U9b9",
        "openStreetMaps": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/252645"
    },
    "population": 11673029,
    "gini": {
        "2019": 41.6
    },
    "fifa": "BOL",
    "car": {
        "signs": [
            "BOL"
        ],
        "side": "right"
    },
    "timezones": [
        "UTC-04:00"
    ],
    "continents": [
        "South America"
    ],
    "flags": {
        "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/bo.png",
        "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/bo.svg"
    },
    "coatOfArms": {
        "png": "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/bo.png",
        "svg": "https://mainfacts.com/media/images/coats_of_arms/bo.svg"
    },
    "startOfWeek": "monday",
    "capitalInfo": {
        "latlng": [
            -19.02,
            -65.26
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

El **JSON** mostrado arriba es cuando busco el continente de **America** y este me trae todos los paises correspondientes a este, aca esta mi codigo PHP mi problema es que como veran en el json languages puede tener de 1 a mas sub propiedades y me piden que recorra todos los languages usados por pais.

```
<form class="" action="" method="get">
    <div class="custom-select">
        <select id="continente" name="continente">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione</option>
            <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
            <option value="Americas">Americas</option>
            <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
            <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
            <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" class="continente" name="button">Mostrar</button>
    </div>

</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>CODIGO (ALFA 3)</th>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>CAPITAL</th>
        <th>POBLACION</th>
        <th>IDIOMAS</th>
        <th>BANDERA (IMAGEN)</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        
          if (isset($_GET['continente']))
          {
              $continente = $_GET['continente'];
              
              $data = json_decode( file_get_contents("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/".$continente), true);
              //print_r($data);
          
              for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
                
                echo "<tr>";  
                  echo "<td>".$data[$i]["fifa"]."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$data[$i]["name"]["common"]."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".str_replace(array('[',']'),'',json_encode($data[$i]["capital"]))."</td>";   
                  echo "<td>".$data[$i]["population"]. " hab." ."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$data[$i]["languages"]."</td>";

                  
                echo  "</tr>";
                
                  $paises = count($data);
              }
             
              echo $continente. " - " .$paises. " paises encontrados";
              
          }
    
    ?>
</table>
```

Haciendole un `var_dump($data[$i]["languages"]);`

me esta arrojando esto

```
array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(4) { ["aym"]=> string(6) "Aymara" ["grn"]=> string(8) "Guaraní" ["que"]=> string(7) "Quechua" ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" }


array(1) { ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" }


array(1) { ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" }


array(1) { ["kal"]=> string(11) "Greenlandic" }


array(3) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" ["nld"]=> string(5) "Dutch" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" }


array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(3) { ["bjz"]=> string(15) "Belizean Creole" ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(2) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" ["jam"]=> string(15) "Jamaican Patois" } array(2) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" }


array(1) { ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" } array(3) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" ["nld"]=> string(5) "Dutch" ["pap"]=> string(10) "Papiamento" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" }


array(1) { ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(3) { ["aym"]=> string(6) "Aymara" ["que"]=> string(7) "Quechua" ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["nld"]=> string(5) "Dutch" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" }


array(1) { ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" }


array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(2) { ["nld"]=> string(5) "Dutch" ["pap"]=> string(10) "Papiamento" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" }



array(1) { ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(2) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" }


array(3) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" ["nld"]=> string(5) "Dutch" ["pap"]=> string(10) "Papiamento" } array(2) { ["fra"]=> string(6) "French" ["hat"]=> string(14) "Haitian Creole" } array(2) { ["grn"]=> string(8) "Guaraní" ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(2) { ["grn"]=> string(8) "Guaraní" ["spa"]=> string(7) "Spanish" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" } array(1) { ["por"]=> string(10) "Portuguese" } array(1) { ["eng"]=> string(7) "English" }
```

Americas - 56 paises encontrados

Comment: El JSON que muestras al inicio de la pregunta NO es un array. Es un JSON con una propiedad llamada `languages` la cual a su vez tiene otras dos propiedades que son `fra` y `hat`. Dado que esa estructura NO es un array, no puedes leerla como tal.

Comment: Si entiendo es un array, pero entonces como haría para que pueda recorrer esas dos propiedades, porque no siempre seran la mismas. Ya que de acuerdo a un **https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/".$continente** me muestra diferentes resultados.

Comment: Pues explica qué parte del JSON exactamente quieres leer, mostrando un ejemplo mínimo del mismo que contenga todas las rutas a las que se debe acceder para llegar a esa parte.

Comment: ok agrege todo el codigo y me explique un poco mejor referente a mi consulta.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner esto en tu código (dentro del `for`) y decirnos qué muestra: `var_dump($data[$i]["languages"]);`? Con un solo resultado bastaría, es para ver si estás correcto en ese punto de tu código. ¿Podrías mostrar también un ejemplo de JSON donde haya más de un idioma, para ver cómo viene la respuesta en esos casos?

Comment: Listo ya realize el var_dump y tambien añadi el json de otro pais con mas idiomas

Comment: OK, está todo perfecto. Para imprimir cada lenguaje sólo tienes que hacer esto dentro del bucle: `foreach ($data[$i]["languages"] as $k=>$v) { echo "$k : $v\n" }`  Esto deberá imprimirte algo así en el caso del país que muestras de ejemplo: `aym : Aymara
grn : Guaraní
que : Quechua
spa : Spanish` y así por cada país... Si no te interesan los nombres de propiedades (valores a la izquierda del JSON) ponlo simplemente así: `foreach ($data[$i]["languages"] as $v) { echo "$v\n" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el JSON que muestras, en la propiedad `languages` habría un array con uno o varios valores:

```
"languages": {
    "aym": "Aymara",
    "grn": "Guaraní",
    "que": "Quechua",
    "spa": "Spanish"
},
```

Para leerlo, simplemente tendrías que recorrer esa propiedad con un bucle interno.

Por ejemplo:

```
          /*
             OJO a esto: en bucles for no conviene usar count dentro
             eso contaría en cada iteracción ...
             Es mejor guardar el total una sola vez
         */
          $total=count($data);

          for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
            
            echo "<tr>";  
              echo "<td>".$data[$i]["fifa"]."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$data[$i]["name"]["common"]."</td>";
              echo "<td>".str_replace(array('[',']'),'',json_encode($data[$i]["capital"]))."</td>";   
              echo "<td>".$data[$i]["population"]. " hab." ."</td>";
              echo "<td>".implode(",",$data[$i]['languages'])."</td>";
              
            echo  "</tr>";
            
            $paises = count($data); # ¿Qué hace esto aquí?
          }
```

Aquí simplemente se ha usado `implode` para mostrar los nombres de idiomas separados por comas. Si por algún motivo te interesan también las propiedades de cada uno de ellos (valores de la izquierda), puedes hacer un `foreach ($data[$i]['languages'] as $k=>$v) { //.... }` Tendrias entonces en `$k` el dato de cada propiedad (valor de la izquierda) y en `$v` los nombres (valor de la derecha), construyendo el `td` según lo que necesites.

#### Post-Data

Considera crear esta variable fuera del bucle: `$paises = count($data);`. Al tenerla dentro, estás recreando constantemente esa variable sin ninguna necesidad. Debes tener cuidado con la optimización del código. Pequeños detalles como estos y lo señalado más arriba sobre el `for` van recargando el código poco a poco y al final podrías tener problemas de rendimiento.

Comment: Buenísimo la explicación e entendido todo. Gracias por el apoyo y la paciencia sobre todo bro. Una consulta esto tambien lo podria realizar en javascript verdad?

Comment: @AlvaroAnthonyUrbanoCardenas sí, también puedes hacerlo en Javascript. Si necesitas hacerlo allí simplemente tienes que aplicar la misma lógica, pero en código Javascript y si tienes algún problema puedes abrir una nueva pregunta pero basada en Javascript. Saludos.